# I am confused with the const keyword in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I have code that passes data through a react component from a form to a backend. The backend processes it and sends a response. However I am confused with the const keyword, I am seeing in the code.

```
axios{
  .post('/api/users/register', newUser)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data }));
```

}

```
render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
     <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={classnames('form-control form-control-lg', {
                  'is-invalid': errors.name
                })}
                placeholder="Name"
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onChange}
      />
```

You can assume that the code works. However, why is `const {errors}` defined like this, and how come it can access the errors list from the backend `is-invalid': errors.name`.

Thank you.

Comment: It's ES6 destructing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. Basically `const { errors } = this.state` is the same as `this.state.errors`. For example, in the `input` you have `value={this.state.value}`. That can also be destructed as `const { value } = this.state`, then `value={value}`. The above error simply states that `errors` doesn't have a property `name`. Try `console.log(error)` to see how `errors` is structured.

Comment: Oops. Second to last sentence is incorrect. Basically when `errors` is being set to state, it's an `object` with properties. In this case, it has a `name` property. However, you can destructure that as well: `const { errors: {name} }  = this.state`. Now the variable `name` is shorthand for `this.state.errors.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called object destructuring.  `const {errors} = this.state;` is a cleaner way of accessing the `errors` key in your local state than typing `this.state.errors` everywhere.  So now when you need to use `errors` you can just pass it in somewhere like this

```js
const {errors} = this.state;

<YourComponent
  errors={errors}
/>
```

Comment: "*typing this.state.errors everywhere*" - given that it is used exactly once, it's not really "cleaner" in this specific example

Comment: No but if you had a good amount of components using a specific property in either the local state or the passed props. It might make sense to use object destructuring to shorten up the code a little